# Is there a bruteforce uses random private keys to find spesific public key as a lottery?

Tags: encryption

I actually know how private key and public key works. But I don't know how to brute force private key. In calculation it is impposible. But with luck anything is possible. What I mean is this: If we know how many digits a private key has in general, and using sha-256 processor, if we calculate from 0-infinity then it is really hard.  But if we start from middle randomly can we find it like in 2 years or 50 years. I assume yes.

So is there a programme brute force randomly for private keys? Or can we do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your math does not make any sense and the world does not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

https://vanity-eth.tk/ will find the private key for any public key given enough time ( "enough time" = probably longer than until the heat death of the universe or something like that, maybe someone did the math and can tell the result in comments)